# Preventing browser timeout on large file uploads

Tags: asp.net, file-upload

I have a nice little file upload control I wrote for ASP.NET webforms that utilizes an IFrame and ASP.NET AJAX.

However, on large uploads, the browser times out before it can finish posting the form.

Is there a way I can increase this?

I'm not really interesting in alternative solutions, so don't suggest changing the entire thing out please. It works good for <5 meg uploads, I'd just like to get it up to about 8mb.

EDIT: Setting the timeout in Page_Load didn't appear to change anything.

Answer (score 11):

You need to update a metabase setting on IIS6 and later. The key is "  AspMaxRequestEntityAllowed" and is expressed in bytes. I highly recommend the Metabase Explorer to make the change, wading through the XML at %systemroot%\system32\inetserv\metabase.xml is possible though.

Metabase Explorer: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/840671

Hmmm, perhaps I'm barking up the wrong tree... you wouldn't be doing 5 MB files if that wasn't already adjusted.

Another stab at it: see your web.config:

```
<system.web>
  <httpRuntime  maxRequestLength="10240" executionTimeout="360"/>
</system.web>
```

Max request length is in kilobytes and execution timeout is in seconds.

Comment: maxRequestLength is actually in kilobytes. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e1f13641.aspx

Comment: You are right otherwise the small number I mention wouldn't make sense. Thanks, edited.

Answer (score 4):

Place this in your web.config

```
  <system.web>
     <httpRuntime executionTimeout="360" maxRequestLength="100000" />
```

That enables a 360 second timeout and 100,000 Kb of upload data at a time.

If that doesn't work, run this command on your IIS server. (replace [IISWebsitename])

```
C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv>appcmd set config "[IISWebsitename]" -section:requestFiltering -requestLimits.maxAllowedContentLength:100000000 -commitpath:apphost
```

That enables 100,000,000 bytes of upload data at a time.

Comment: Thanks! The requestFiltering parameter did the trick for me. In IIS 7, I made the change with the following command: Request Filtering | Rules | Edit Feature Settings | Maximum allowed content length.

Answer (score 2):

In Page_Load, set Server.ScriptTimeout to a value that works for you.  Measured in seconds I believe.

Comment: You would do this in the actual iframe that gets posted back, correct?

Comment: Yes, if you are getting the request timeout in the iframe, then that would where you set Server.ScriptTimeout.

Answer (score 1):

I think you may need to adjust the [MaxRequestLength](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.httpruntimesection.maxrequestlength.aspx)

Its in the Web.config I think by default its 4megs.

The following would allow ~10 meg file:

```
<httpRuntime maxRequestLength="10240" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Open your Web.config file, and just below the `<system.web>` tag, add the following tag:

`<httpRuntime 
    executionTimeout="90" 
    maxRequestLength="4096" 
    useFullyQualifiedRedirectUrl="false" 
    minFreeThreads="8" 
    minLocalRequestFreeThreads="4" 
    appRequestQueueLimit="100" 
    enableVersionHeader="true"
    />`

Now, just take a look at the maxRequestLength="4096" attribute of the `<httpRuntime>` tag. As you may have realized, all you need to do is change the value to some other value of your choice (8192 for 8 Mb, 16384 for 16 Mb, 65536 for 64 Mb, and so on...).

Answer (score -7):

Check the code of [Velodoc XP Edition](http://www.codeplex.com/VelodocXP). It includes an upload streaming module, a resumable download handler and ASP.NET upload controls based on ASP.NET Ajax extensions and it is all open source.

For more information check also [www.memba.com](http://www.memba.com) and [www.velodoc.com](http://www.velodoc.com).

Comment: This doesn't directly address the question, and it may be an advertisement.

Comment: Website linked to is not currently in use.

Answer (score -7):

I solved this using PHP with HTML:

1. I start a session
2. enter a loop
3. create a loop that reloads the page that does part of the job at a
   time
4. do until job is done
5. the code inside the loop does a portion of the job
6. increment a session variable to point to next part of the job
7. reload the page using java script //this will restart the severs
   page timer
8. loop
9. load a page to report the job is done