# Connection Reset due to large file upload but configs should permit upload

Tags: asp.net-mvc, file-upload, connection-reset

I am having errors attempting to upload a file larger than 4 megs in my MVC project. The upload works fine for smaller files. Looking online, I saw that I should add

`<httpRuntime maxRequestLength="200000" executionTimeout="240"/>`

to my web config, in system web, but that has had no effect. The connection is still resetting.  Are there other configs that need to be changed that I may have missed? The file is 10 megs, so that request length is plenty large enough.

The request is not timing out, the connection is reset instantly.

I also tried adding

```
<security >
  <requestFiltering>
    <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="1024000000" />
  </requestFiltering>
</security>`
```

to my webserver section in web config, but that had no effect either. The web config is the one located in the correct project, and the connection never reaches the breakpoint located in my controller, which makes me believe that this must be a config problem where an http request with a too-large file is being rejected.  If that is the case, why doesn't the maxrequestlength attribute fix the problem?

Comment: Could it be your session\browser timeout?  Which library are you using to upload?  check http://stackoverflow.com/a/230916/643500

Comment: I am uploading by using 
     `  <input type="file" name="datafile" id = "0" />`
I read that question... it says to add the httpruntime attributes exactly as I did, which is why I am confused.  Again, the problem is not a timeout. The connection reset occurs instantaneously, not after a 10 second timeout or something like that.

Comment: is your httpRuntime surrounded by System.Web like <System.Web>
    <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="value in kilobytes" />
</System.Web>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

:/. Found the problem. I had been adding maxRequestLength to the wrong web config. There is one webconfig file in views, and one in the full project. I was putting it inside of views. Wasn't even aware of the fact that there were 2, and several people missed it as well. Terrible design to put two identically named and similarly purposed files inside of the project, seperated by only one layer of file depth.

Answer (score 2):

just an update for IIS 7.x

you will need to add the following for newer versions of IIS:

```
<security>
    <requestFiltering>
          <requestLimits maxUrl="32767" maxQueryString="32767" 
            maxAllowedContentLength="2147483648"/>
    </requestFiltering>
</security>
```

Answer (score 0):

Update for IIS 10x, add the following to the web.config for the site:

```
  <requestFiltering>
    <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="500000000"></requestLimits>
  </requestFiltering>
```

Problem solved straight away. Found this following the steps here: http://d4dotnet.blogspot.com/2011/11/there-was-no-endpoint-listening-at.html

Steps 1 and 3 cause a server failure until removed, presumably they are either specific to IIS 6 and 7 or belong to another config file.