# file upload restarts partway through upload to AWS instance

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, file-upload, amazon-web-services

When uploading a file the upload appears to restart partway through the upload.

Part of our management system involves uploading files to be processed on the server. The files can be quite large (around 70Mb) normally text and image files. It is a c# MVC application on IIS 7.

This all works fine on the development setup but not on our live system hosted on Amazon Web services.

I have 3 test files:
70Mb, 35Mb and 10Mb

the 10Mb file reaches 100%, displays a 'waiting for page' message in the status bar and then starts uploading again.
the 35Mb file reaches 40% and then restarts the upload
the 70Mb file reaches 18% and then restarts the upload

All of the restarts happen between 2 minutes and 2 minute 20 seconds into the upload. The same behavior is seen in chrome and firefox.

I've set the `httpRuntime` `maxRequestLength` and `executionTimeout` to be sufficiently large enough. Debug is set to false in the live system

I've set the `requestFiltering` and `maxAllowedContentLength` to be sufficiently large also.

It doesn't seem like the code in the controllers is being reached. I think it's a config issue but i'm not sure what i've missed.

I've looked at [Connection Reset due to large file upload but configs should permit upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10741568/connection-reset-due-to-large-file-upload-but-configs-should-permit-upload) which seems similar apart from my issues occur at around the 2 minute mark, not straight away.

Update: I've run through the process again with fiddler and this returns a `504 gateway timeout` status

Update: This process works ok with smaller files (1Mb to 6Mb tested so far)